# Field tracking functionality for long / rich field

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

I want to track a long field on chatter.But i came to know the standard functionality of salesforce that rich / long field's old and new value are not posted.

I hope this can be achieved using apex .

Could you please guide me how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance and a very happy weekend
Ankita

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying the idea posted in the below link to achieve this.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&id=90630000000gyjCAAQ

Regards!
Ruchi

Comment: i want the api's which i need to use here

Comment: Can someone help me over here